# Login screen appears in a much older style

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen

The login screen appears in a much older style:

[image: login window]

Output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`:

```
/usr/bin/xdm
```

How can I change it back to normal?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`?

Comment: It's /usr/bin/xdm

Answer (score 8):

You have set your default display manager to `xdm` in place of the default more modern `lightdm` or `gdm`

You should be able to change back to your preferred display manager by reconfiguring the package using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xdm
```

and then navigating the menu with your arrow and <kbd>TAB</kbd> keys and confirming your selection with the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key or <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>.

[image: dpkg-reconfigure xdm]

The choice will take effect next time you reboot - or you can stop then re-start the display manager manually using `systemctl` (note that this will terminate any running desktop session as well):

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

then

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

Comment: It worked!!! I changed it to gdm3