# Ubuntu old login page

Tags: 20.04, login, i3-wm

After installing i3, when I restarted the system, I came across this page

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Login screen appears in a much older style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997620/login-screen-appears-in-a-much-older-style)

Comment: Thank you it works❤

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login screen appears in a much older style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997620/login-screen-appears-in-a-much-older-style)